# Python Polars: Unique values in each row

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe with 150 columns of currency codes. I can identify them with a regex expression `df.select(pl.col('^*cur$'))`. I am trying to determine the unique set of currency codes in each row. Nulls should be ignored.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1cur": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
        "col2cur": [None, "EUR", None],
        "col3cur": ["EUR", None, None],
        "col4cur": ["EUR", "GBP", None],
        "target": [["EUR"], ["EUR", "GBP"], ["EUR"]]
    }
)
```

In pandas, I would do this. Can anyone help, on how I would approach this in Polars?

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1cur": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
        "col2cur": [None, "EUR", None],
        "col3cur": ["EUR", None, None],
        "col4cur": ["EUR", "GBP", None],
    },
    dtype="string",
)

pandas_df["target"] = pandas_df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().unique()).to_list(), axis=1
)
```

Comment: why is that the target? what if there's multiple non-null values? shouldn't the second row have both EUR and GBP

Comment: Yes - I have made an edit to the post

Answer (score 2):

Since polars isn't really good at row operations, I'd start off with a melt.

```
df.drop('target').with_row_count('i').join(
    df.drop('target').with_row_count('i').melt('i').filter(~pl.col('value').is_null()) \
      .groupby('i').agg(pl.col('value').unique()), 
   on='i'
).sort('i').drop('i')
```

We just do a `with_row_count` to create an index to maintain the identity of the original rows, then filter out the nulls, then groupby what was previously each row, aggregate to unique, and lastly wrap it in a join with the original columns by the row index.

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ col1cur ┆ col2cur ┆ col3cur ┆ col4cur ┆ value          │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---            │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════╡
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ ["EUR"]        │
│ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ GBP     ┆ ["GBP", "EUR"] │
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ ["EUR"]        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the closest I could get:

```py
In [39]: df.with_columns(pl.concat_list(pl.col('*')).arr.unique().alias('target'))
Out[39]:
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ col1cur ┆ col2cur ┆ col3cur ┆ col4cur ┆ target               │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---                  │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ list[str]            │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ [null, "EUR"]        │
│ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ GBP     ┆ ["EUR", null, "GBP"] │
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ [null, "EUR"]        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

I'll update the answer if/when I find a way to exclude nulls

---

Slower solution, but which excludes nulls:

```py
In [44]: df.with_columns(pl.concat_list(pl.col('*')).apply(lambda x: list(set(i for i in x if i is not None))).alias('target'))
Out[44]:
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ col1cur ┆ col2cur ┆ col3cur ┆ col4cur ┆ target         │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---            │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════╡
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ ["EUR"]        │
│ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ GBP     ┆ ["EUR", "GBP"] │
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ ["EUR"]        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot further than I had got using `concat_str`.

Comment: happy to help - I've added a way to do it with apply, which is a bit slower, but actually excludes nulls

Comment: Would be handy if there was an `.arr.drop_nulls()` - you can implement it with `.arr.eval()` e.g. `.arr.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_not_null()), parallel=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the concat_list with arr_eval.

```
df.drop('target').with_columns(
    pl.concat_list('*').arr.eval(pl.element().unique().drop_nulls(), parallel=True).alias('target'))
```

This is similar to what @jcurious proposed in his comment.

Here is the result:

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ col1cur ┆ col2cur ┆ col3cur ┆ col4cur ┆ target         │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---            │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════╡
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ ["EUR"]        │
│ EUR     ┆ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ GBP     ┆ ["EUR", "GBP"] │
│ EUR     ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ ["EUR"]        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

Edit: added parallel=True to arr.eval, to run the evaluation in parallel. (suggestion of @jqurious)

Comment: Didn't realize I was over-complicating things with the `.filter()` - very nice approach. It seems adding `parallel=True` could also be worthwhile in this case.