# Finding (unique) set of values across columns

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars Dataframe that looks like the below

| id | attribute | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | A | A | A |
| 2 | True | A | A | B |
| 2 | False | A | B | C |

I would like to create a new column that is the set of the values in val1, val2, and val3.  For example,

| id | attribute | val1 | val2 | val3 | set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | A | A | A | A |
| 2 | True | A | A | B | A, B |
| 2 | False | A | B | C | A, B, C |

I can do something like this,

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'attribute': [True, True, False],
    'val1': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
    'val2': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'val3': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    })
df = df.with_columns([pl.struct('^val.*$').alias('set')])
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('set').apply(lambda x: set(x.values())))
```

However, with the apply, it is predictable slow.  Is there a way to do this using native Polars functionality?

Comment: Would any of these solutions work for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372024/python-polars-unique-values-in-each-row

Comment: Maybe it's downvoted because your example is not runnable. If you don't also provide code to produce your example dataframe e.g. `df = ...` - it requires people to manually re-create it.

Comment: @Chris please post a reproducible example, along with expected output

Comment: @jqurious, thanks for pointing that out. I've made the example runnable.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, thanks for pointing that out. I've made the example runnable.

Comment: @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ, thank you for pointing out that question.  That is very close to what I needed.  The use of "arr" with unique that was the unlock.  It's unfortunately still not as fast as I would like, but at least I know its not because of the apply now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/75387840/ as @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ pointed out.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.concat_list(pl.col("^val.*$"))
     .arr.eval(
        pl.element().unique(maintain_order=True).drop_nulls(),
        parallel=True)
     .alias("set")
)
```

```
shape: (3, 6)
┌─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  | attribute | val1 | val2 | val3 | set             │
│ --- | ---       | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---             │
│ i64 | bool      | str  | str  | str  | list[str]       │
╞═════╪═══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   | true      | A    | A    | A    | ["A"]           │
│ 2   | true      | A    | A    | B    | ["A", "B"]      │
│ 3   | false     | A    | B    | C    | ["A", "B", "C"] │
└─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────────────────┘
```